# Debouncing with formik, yup and axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, lodash, yup

trying to debounce an api call to check and see if a given email address has already been taken.

here is faulty logic for that.

```
const request = email => {
  return Axios.get(
    'http://localhost:4000/api/v1/users/precheck?user[email]=' + email,
  ).then(response => {
    return response.data.precheck == 'ok';
  });
};

const checkEmail = _.debounce(request, 1000);

export const Signup = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: () => ({ email: '' }),
  validationSchema: object().shape({
    email: string()
      .email('Invalid email address')
      .required('Email is required!')
      .test('email', 'email already taken', email => {
        _.debounce(checkEmail(email));
      }),
  }),
 ...
})(InnerForm);
```

this will produce

```
createValidation.js:63 Uncaught (in promise) ValidationError {name: "ValidationError", value: "aaa", path: "email", type: undefined, errors: Array(1), …}
Promise.then (async)
validate @ createValidation.js:107
(anonymous) @ mixed.js:245
(anonymous) @ mixed.js:244
Promise.then (async)
_validate @ mixed.js:238
validate @ mixed.js:256
(anonymous) @ object.js:202
(anonymous) @ object.js:188
Promise.then (async)
_validate @ object.js:179
validate @ mixed.js:256
validateYupSchema @ formik.esm.js:547
(anonymous) @ formik.esm.js:205
Formik._this.runValidationSchema @ formik.esm.js:200
Formik._this.runValidations @ formik.esm.js:217
executeChange @ formik.esm.js:257
Formik._this.handleChange @ formik.esm.js:269
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:100
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:138
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:187
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:201
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:461
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:483
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:581
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:592
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:560
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:723
runExtractedEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:732
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:4476
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:16659
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2131
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4555
interactiveUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:16714
interactiveUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2150
dispatchInteractiveEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4532
formik.esm.js:529 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at yupToFormErrors (formik.esm.js:529)
    at formik.esm.js:208
yupToFormErrors @ formik.esm.js:529
(anonymous) @ formik.esm.js:208
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ formik.esm.js:205
Formik._this.runValidationSchema @ formik.esm.js:200
Formik._this.runValidations @ formik.esm.js:217
executeChange @ formik.esm.js:257
Formik._this.handleChange @ formik.esm.js:269
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:100
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:138
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:187
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:201
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:461
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:483
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:581
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:592
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:560
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:723
runExtractedEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:732
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:4476
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:16659
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2131
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4555
interactiveUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:16714
interactiveUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2150
dispatchInteractiveEvent @ react-dom.development.js:4532
```

Comment: I'm far from a Formik expert, but should you really debounce the validation function itself? Would it not be better to use `email => request(email)` for validation, and debounce the entire `handleChange` function instead?

Comment: I think that could cause sync issues with the other validations for email that dont require a debounce.

Comment: Alright. Have you stumbled upon [this gist by Jared, the creator of Formik](https://gist.github.com/jaredpalmer/a8faaab12bc37e6a160a3c9549664f0b)?

Comment: nice, thank you will check it out!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still looking, here's how i managed to do it:

```
export function asyncDebounce(func: any, wait: any): (...args: any[]) => Promise<unknown> {
  const debounced: DebouncedFunc<(resolve: any, reject: any, bindSelf: any, args: any) => Promise<void>> =
    debounce(async (resolve: any, reject: any, bindSelf: any, args: any) => {
      try {
        const result: any = await func.bind(bindSelf)(...args);
        resolve(result);
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    }, wait);

  // This is the function that will be bound by the caller, so it must contain the `function` keyword.
  function returnFunc(...args: any[]) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
      // @ts-ignore
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-invalid-this
      debounced(resolve, reject, this, args);
    });
  }

  return returnFunc;
}
```

But now you have to use ref and raw apollo query:

```
  const apolloClient: ApolloClient<any> = useApolloClient();

  const emailAddressDebounce: React.MutableRefObject<(...args: any[]) => Promise<unknown>> =
  useRef(asyncDebounce(apolloClient.query, 350));
```

```
email: Yup.string()
        .email('Invalid email address')
        .required('Required')
        .test(
          'email-backend-validation',
          'Email already in use',
          async (email: string | undefined) => {
            if (!email) {
              return true;
            }

            const result: EmailTakenQueryData = await emailAddressDebounce.current({
              query: emailAddressTakenQuery,
              variables: { email },
            }) as unknown as EmailTakenQueryData;

            if (result?.data?.emailAddressTaken) {
              return !result?.data?.emailAddressTaken;
            }

            return true;
          }),
```

and this works :)